# is appscript able to send a message/notification?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a simple dialog box in google sheets:

```
var userChoice = ui.alert('Are you Shure you want to overite time?', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    if (userChoice == ui.Button.OK) {
      ui.alert('Operation Confirmed.');
    } else {
      ui.alert('Operation Halted.');
      return;
    }
```

Is there different Method than `alert` for sending a message to the user without opening a dialog box?
I would like to have it just pop up like the "[Script is running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grTm5.png)" notification and disappear after a few seconds.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your goal, in your situation, how about using `toast`? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#toastmsg,-title,-timeoutseconds)

Comment: There is `Spreadsheet.toast()`